# Create a non root user for MySQL with minimal right as using root is not secure

Tags: mysql

General rule for root MySQL user is from infosec point of view:

"Do not use root for any web application for MySQL connection, Select, Update, or Delete queries. Instead of create and use another MySQL user with minimal right."

Ok. What are minimal rights needed for such user, and how can I do it MySQL ? I haven't found any guideline / article about this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: VTC'd for migration to serverfault.SE

Comment: Sorry, i will post these.

Comment: @TassMark IMO, posts that reference external facts, like general rules, seem to do better with reference links

Comment: My Billy Mays ad pitch: Ask yourself. Does my web app need to be able to drop my entire database or other databases root has access to? Does it need to access all tables in the database? Do I want my end user to be able to do these things? If you answered no to any of these then root is not for you! Now introducing orange scented user permissions!